# Offsite payment gateway for Spring MVC supporting MENA region

Tags: spring-mvc, paypal, payflowlink, firstdata, payfort

I am currently in the process of integrating a payment gateway to my Spring MVC application (javascript front end) which will accept payments from users mostly in [MENA](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/middle-east-and-north-africa-mena.asp) region.

The required process of payment is to sent the user offsite for payments and redirect to my application (Offsite redirect).

I prefer using one of  [paypal](https://www.paypal.com/home) , [First data](https://www.firstdata.com/en_eg/home.html) or [Payfort](http://www.payfort.com/) .

Expected characteristics of the gateways are as follows,

- PCI compliance : As i am not going to implement them.
- Offsite payments and redirect
- Recurrent billing
- Should accept VISA, Master card and AMEX
- Requirement of a merchant account to receive payments (prefer not to have one)

From the research done so far I have found **all of them** are adhering to **PCI** standards and  supports most of above requirements and i have no concerns regarding their charges.

I have found **paypal** offers [payflow](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway) and **payflow link** but i have some concerns because it is marked as a legacy product , it is said that it will only be available for pre-existing customers and found some articles which implied paypal having issues when used in MENA.  I concentrated on paypal more because of their [Secure Token](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/) method.

I contacted support from all three above mentioned companies and **payfort** confirmed having all above characteristics. Others yet to reply.

I would be much appreciated if someone actually used any above mentioned gateways could give me some advice for choosing the best option. If anyone have integrated any payment gateway other than above 3 for same set of requirements, please share.

Note : If my question have false information it is due to my lack of knowledge in this area as this is the first time i am working with payment gateways. Feel free to correct me.